# Simple calculator program not showing proper output

Tags: java, android

I have some simple code where I input two numbers in `EditText` fields, add them together, and show them in a `TextView`.

Here is my code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="Clear"
    android:onClick="Clicked" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:text="Total"
    android:onClick="Clicked" />
```

And here is my `Clicked` method:

```
public void Clicked(View v) {    
    int  total; 
    EditText t1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText t2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    TextView tv=  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    if(v.getId()==R.id.button1)
    {     
        total= Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString()+t2.getText().toString());
        tv.setText(total);
        tv.setVisibility(1);
    }
    else if (v.getId()==R.id.button2)
    {
        t1.setText("");
        t2.setText("");
    }
}
```

I input two numbers and when I press **clear** it works fine but the total button does not add. Instead, this happens:

[image]

It might be a problem with my integer casting or a problem with logic.

Comment: Please post the logcat which shows what exception is thrown when your app crashes. You can run `adb logcat -d` from the command-line to do this (assuming `adb` is in your PATH).

Comment: The visibility Constants are 0,4,and 8 but I just tried it with 1 and it seemed to work. But I don't know if this will always work or not. So, probably not your problem but I would use the constants VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, and GONE just to be safe and for better readibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its stopped because you may be setting a Int value to setText of TextView. You need to convert it to String

**textView.setText(CharSequence text)**

```
int v1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());
int v2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString());
total = v1 + v2;
tv.setText(total+""); //this converts total to string
//tv.setText(total.toString());   //can use either
```

Comment: Thank u very much brother its working now  ,, such stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
total= Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString()+t2.getText().toString());
```

To this:

```
int v1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());
int v2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString());
total = v1 + v2;
```

Comment: same result  . its stopped.

Comment: Like @Code-Guru commented and others endorsed, you'll have to post your LogCat for us to be able help determine where (else) your app is crashing.

Comment: P.S. Make sure there are valid numbers in both of your `EditText` fields. Later, once you have this working, you will have to special case the possibility of empty numeric fields or illegal characters. You can safeguard with `TextWatcher` filters or enable/disable of the calculate buttons based on content.

Comment: infect i dont know how to  check  LogCat  its giving some abstract info in  LogCat   tab